# Play Office 365 AES encrypted token authenticated video on iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, office365api, azure-media-services

I'm using Azure media player ([Official Documentation](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/)) to play the Office 365 videos. It plays on all browsers except on iOS devices.
I have tried to use [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-make-token-authorized-aes-encrypted-hls-stream-working-in-safari/) solution and it does not work for me.

Could anyone guide me how to get rid of this problem.

Following is the code-block.

```
$.when(
        tokenPromise,
        urlPromise
        )
        .done(function (tokenRes, urlRes) {
            var token = tokenRes.GetStreamingKeyAccessToken;
            var url = urlRes.GetPlaybackUrl;
            $("#modal-"+index).attr("token", token);
            $("#modal-"+index).attr("token-acquired", new Date().toISOString());
            $("#modal-"+index).attr("player-url", url);
            $("#modal-" + index + " .vjs-loading-spinner").hide();
            player.poster(poster);

            player.src([{
                src: url,
                type: "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml",
                protectionInfo:
                        [{
                            type: "AES",
                            authenticationToken: token }]
            }]);


        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check https://github.com/AzureMediaServicesSamples/HLSSafariProxy.

Article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-make-token-authorized-aes-encrypted-hls-stream-working-in-safari/ describes solution in a sample.